# How to prevent the next step when no results from "Get Entities" in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Get Entities (from Azure Table Storage) is the first action in my Logic Apps. Based on the results, rest of the steps will proceed. Please anyone let me know how to stop the execution of next action when there is no results from Get Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `condition` in your `azure logic app` to determine whether the number of entities returned by `Get entities` is greater than 0.

You can use [length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#length) to get the number of results of `Get entities`.

If it is greater than 0, execute the original workflow in `True`, if it is equal to 0, do nothing.

The expression of `condition` is:

```
length(body('Get_entities')?['value'])
```

[image]

Comment: But I am not able to use "Initialize Variable" action. (I hope you remember my previous post that you have replied). I am using "Initialize Variable" action to set my Email Body content based on HTML output from "Create HTML table" action.

Comment: You can use [compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuBtD.png) to replace it.